# How can I select rows from a table where three or more values in different columns are the same?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Hello I've been working on this all morning. I thought it was a simple self join but the self join actually returns too many rows.

Essentially I'm trying to find rows in a table where certain column values match row to row.

So if row one and three have the same column values in three specific columns then those two rows are returned.

So far I've tried a self-join, and a semi-join in a couple of different ways.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ATable a, ATable b
Where  a.colValue = b.colValue
and    a.colValue2 = b.colValue2
```

This returns too many rows.
Is this query even a join? Am I on the wrong track here?
What am I missing about self joins that it returns more rows than the table itself?

ATable contains 20 rows but above query returns 36.

As Always thanks very much for any answers or hints. I learn alot just by formulating the question.

Comment: might want to add `and a.id <> b.id` in order to eliminate matching itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query at the moment will return every row, because all rows are equal to themselves.
You need to restrict it so that they must be different rows.

I'm assuming you have some sort of Primary Key ID column.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ATable a, ATable b
Where  a.colValue = b.colValue
and    a.colValue2 = b.colValue2
and    a.Id!= b.Id
```

Another thing you have to consider is that if you had the rows:

```
ID      ColValue     ColValue2   ColValue3
1           A            B            C
2           A            B            D
```

You'd see:

```
a.id a.ColValue a.ColValue2 a.ColValue3 b.id b.ColValue b.ColValue2 b.ColValue3
1    A          B           C           2    A          B           D
2    A          B           D           1    A          B           C
```

Because Row 1 is the same as Row 2.  But also Row 2 is the same as Row 1.

Comment: Funny thing is I don't actually have a rowID as every field can allow duplicates. (It's an oracle temp table technically) so I'll have to add one I guess so I have some kind of distinct value to compare. Thanks very much for answering this.

Comment: Oh and I should add here that Oracle has a pseudocolumn already called rowid so i don;t even have to actually make and maintain a pk if I don't need it. d'uh on me.

Answer (score 1):

you are doing it right... for each row, you will get itself, and all other rows that match the columns you specify, that should be a MINIMUM of the total number of rows in the table, and probably more.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, only trouble is I only need that row that matches returned one time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to find duplicate rows?

```
SELECT count(a.id) as cnt
FROM ATable a
GROUP BY a.colValue
WHERE cnt>1
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm not actually looking for duplicate rows, just rows where 3 of about 7 column values are the same with at least one other row in the same table.

Comment: This problem first has seemed to me equivalent to finding the same lines) Sorry)